# What exactly is meant by a Template Engine in computing?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

From Cash Costello's Elgg 1.8 Social Networking page 287 under What template engine is used? he says, 'Elgg uses PHP as its template engine.'

What exactly is meant by a Template Engine?

***Full extract:***

What template engine is used?

Elgg uses PHP as its template engine. This results in a flexible view system since the full power of PHP is available. Developers also do not have to learn a new template language to use Elgg as they would with an engine like Smarty. On the downside, an expressive template language such as PHP is a temptation to mix controller code into the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template (in this context) is an HTML file whose contents are dynamically filled in to produce the final page you're seeing. There are myriads of ways how this "dynamic filling in" can happen, from specialised XML transformation syntaxes to DOM manipulators. "PHP as a template engine" just means that they're using PHP as it was designed: embedded PHP snippets inside of HTML.

If you only know PHP, it may seem strange to you that this needs specific mention. Other languages are not designed to be embeddable inside other languages, so templating is a bit more of a complex task and usually calls for special "templating engines". Such things are becoming more popular in PHP as well though, mostly because their syntax can be simpler and more manageable and they enforce separation of concerns better.

For example, compare to [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org).

Comment: This is a great answer. I started web development using PHP, but then moved on to Java. I've been trying to find out exactly what it means to have a templating engine, and this answer is really helpful.